# Python unicode.splitlines() triggers at non-EOL character

Tags: python, unicode

Triyng to make this in Python 2.7:

```
>>> s = u"some\u2028text"
>>> s
u'some\u2028text'
>>> l = s.splitlines(True)
>>> l
[u'some\u2028', u'text']
```

`\u2028` is Left-To-Right Embedding character, not `\r` or `\n`, so that line should not be splitted. Is there a bug or just my misunderstanding?

Comment: `\u2028` is `LINE SEPARATOR`, left-to-right embedding is `\u202A`

Comment: @pavel-anossov Thank you. now I break the habit looking up Unicode characters in Windows charmap.

Comment: interesting, my charmap is fine: http://i.imgur.com/jwkyMEm.png

Comment: @pavel-annosov now try to find "line separator".

Comment: it is missing from Arial, but present in Lucida Sans Unicode, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\u2028` is LINE SEPARATOR, left-to-right embedding is `\u202A`:

```py
>>> import unicodedata

>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2028')
'LINE SEPARATOR'

>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u202A')
'LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING'
```

---

The list of codepoints considered linebreaks is easy (not that easy to find though) to see in python source (python 2.7, comments by me):

```c
/* Returns 1 for Unicode characters having the line break
 * property 'BK', 'CR', 'LF' or 'NL' or having bidirectional
 * type 'B', 0 otherwise.
 */
int _PyUnicode_IsLinebreak(register const Py_UNICODE ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
    // Basic Latin
    case 0x000A:    // LINE FEED
    case 0x000B:    // VERTICAL TABULATION
    case 0x000C:    // FORM FEED
    case 0x000D:    // CARRIAGE RETURN
    case 0x001C:    // FILE SEPARATOR
    case 0x001D:    // GROUP SEPARATOR
    case 0x001E:    // RECORD SEPARATOR

    // Latin-1 Supplement
    case 0x0085:    // NEXT LINE

    // General punctuation
    case 0x2028:    // LINE SEPARATOR
    case 0x2029:    // PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that great module.

Answer (score 2):

[`U+2028`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Unicode_introduced_separators) is `LINE SEPARATOR`. Both `U+2028` and `U+2029` (`PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR`) *should* be treated as newlines, so Python is doing the right thing.

Of course it is sometimes perfectly reasonable to want to split on a non-standard list of newline characters. But you can't do that with [`splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). You will have to use [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)—and, if you need the additional features of `splitlines`, you'll have to implement them yourself. For example:

```
return [line.rstrip(sep) for line in s.split(sep)]
```

Comment: The deal is that I use `codecs` module which uses `splitlines()`. In my case it's easier to ignore some garbage characters from input rather than write my own parser.

Comment: @Pehat: Well, `codecs` uses `splitlines` when you use universal-newlines mode, and it's the same thing: you can't use universal newlines either if you want a non-standard list of newline characters. But it's not as easy to replace that as in the `splitlines` case… (As a side note, whatever you're using `codecs` for, you may want to strongly consider using `io` instead.)